# Can't install Microsoft.AspNet.Session

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

A simple question: why can't I install `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` in my project?

My project.json file:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WNCT.Web-f78556bf-e147-4ae1-befa-681a6422744f",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Session" : "1.0.0-beta6",
    "WNCT.BL": "1.0.0-*",
    "WNCT.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "WNCT.EF": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "HtmlAgilityPack": "1.0.0-*",
        "LDAP": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },

    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `dnxcore50` and after a restore I got a bunch of error for core but after removing core everything was restored correctly. Weird but I guess understandable from a beta.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the Beta 6 version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` and the Beta 5 version of everything else.

Beta 6 just came out today. Consider updating everything to Beta 6 by following the instructions in the [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/07/27/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta-6.aspx) or drop back to Beta 5 only.